# Matching items in a recommender system

Tags: machine-learning, recommender-system, similarity

I would like to ask for a proposal for a machine learning model that would be suitable for the following problem:

I have a training set where each element of type A corresponds to a certain number of elements of type B (both type A and type B elements are described by certain specific columns), i.e.:

A_1 -> B_1, A_1 -> B_2, A_1 -> B_3

A_2 -> B_4, A_2 -> B_5

A_3 -> B_6 ...

For a new element of type A, I want to select the most matching elements of type B from a certain set and indicate how many percent the elements match each other.

Can the problem formulated in this way be solved by machine learning or should I reformulate it in some way?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can approach the problem use case using a collaborative filtering method. To make recommendations, collaborative filtering algorithms take into account user preferences or behaviour. The relationship between type A and type B items in your situation is the behaviour or desire.

Comment: From review: can you please add some links to information about collaborative filtering so the OP and other interested people can find out more about this.

Comment: Hello @Lynn, yes I would recommend these links:

1. Collaborative Filtering for Implicit Feedback Datasets https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/4781121

2. Item-based collaborative filtering recommendation algorithms
https://dl.acm.org/doi/10.1145/371920.372071